# Set the legend location of a pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, legend-properties

I know how to set the legend location of matplotlib plot with `plt.legend(loc='lower left')`, however, I am plotting with pandas method `df.plot()` and need to set the legend location to 'lower left'.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Edited: I am actually looking for a way to do it through pandas' `df.plot()`, not via `plt.legend(loc='lower left')`

Comment: Can you show an example code where `plt.legend(loc='lower left')` does not work?

Comment: @danielLima Just call `plt.legend(loc='lower left')` after calling `df.plot(...)`

Comment: Hi, I am actually looking into a way to do it via pandas, when calling df.plot()

Comment: Yes, but the command is the same. So unless you can show a code where `plt.legend(loc='lower left')` does not give the desired result, the question is not very useful.

Comment: @DanielLima Pandas plotting is just a layer upon matplotlib.  Pandas brings its own way of passing data, but the settings are all handled by matplotlib. It doesn't make sense for Pandas to copy all of matplotlib's extensive functionality. Pandas quickly creates a plot from dataframes. If you need finetuning, there comes matplotlib.

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at my answer? I can add more explanation if it is still unclear

Comment: I have edited my answer in response to your edit, I would recommend taking a look

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With pandas 1.5.3 you can chain legend() behind plot()
see [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.legend.html).

Example:

```
matched.set_index(
    matched.index.date
).plot(kind='barh', stacked=True
).legend(
    bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1.0),
    fontsize='small',
);
```

[image: Screenshot Jupyter cell]

Answer (score 50):

Well, Simply chain it.

```
dframe.rank(ascending=False).plot(kind= 'bar').legend(loc='best')
```

Assuming 'dframe' is a DataFrame.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Very nice solution :-)

Comment: Docs for ```.legend``` are at https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html

Comment: Not working for pandas 1.3.5. I get "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'legend'" when trying df.plot().legend()

Answer (score 25):

### Edit

To clarify the original answer, there is presently no way to do this through [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html). In its current implementation (version 1.2.3) the `'legend'` argument of `plot` accepts only a boolean or the string `'reverse'`:

> **legend** : *False/True/'reverse'*
>    Place legend on axis subplots

It does not accept legend position strings. The remaining `**kwargs` are passed into the underlying `matplotlib.pyplot` method which corresponds to the specified `'kind'` argument (defaults to `matplotlib.pyplot.plot`). **None** of those methods allow for legend positioning via their keyword arguments.

Therefore, the **only** way to do this at present is to use `plt.legend()` directly - as outlined in my original answer, below.

---

As the comments indicate, you have to use `plt.legend(loc='lower left')` to put the legend in the lower left. Even when using [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) - there is no parameter which adjusts legend position, only if the legend is drawn. Here is a complete example to show the usage

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.random.random(100)

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y':y})
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='x', y='y', label='Scatter')
plt.legend(loc='lower left')
plt.show()
```

[image]